# Что плохого в установке российских корневых сертификатов на личные ПК?

Tags: https, криптография, сертификат

Видел [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/663340/) о том, как легко распространить корневые сертификаты Минцифры на личные ПК сотрудников. Некоторые комментарии к статье указывали на небезопасность такой операции:

> Надеюсь, Вы предупреждаете сотрудников о всех рисках установки корневого сертификата ЦА Минцифры на их домашние компьютеры, прежде чем рассылать описанный exe-шник...

> ...ценой установки чёрт знает чьих сертификатов в доверенные. За подобное руки отрывать надо.

Отдельные комментарии указывают на конкретные риски:

> Риск в том что становится возможна атака man-in-the-middle от Минцифры. Вы идете на gmail с https, а какой-нибудь СОРМ у провайдера вам подменяет сертификат на свой и читает всю вашу переписку. У вас при этом будет зеленый замочек.

Если корневой УЦ Минцифры может выполнить атаку "человек посередине", то наверно её может провести любой корневой УЦ? Почему комментарии критикуют именно УЦ Минцифры?

> в отношении коммерческого УЦ, который рискует многомиллиардным бизнесом, риски утечки ключа на порядки ниже, чем в отношении министерства

> в случае, если станет известно об утечке ключа доверенного корневого УЦ, можно рассчитывать на незамедлительный отзыв такого сертификата всеми браузерами; в случае, если станет известно об утечке ключа Минцифры, можно рассчитывать на очередное "это фейк и ничего у нас не утекало"

Но ведь не только пользовательские сертификаты приводят по цепочке к корневому сертификату Минцифры, но и сертификаты госструктур, в частности - налоговой инспекции, МВД (я проверил цепочку сертификатов одного из документов, полученных от МВД). Утечка корневого сертификата Минцифры приведёт к компрометации многих электронных документов государства, так что, на мой взгляд, у министерства риски тоже достаточно высоки.

Так почему же мы не должны доверять корневому сертификату Минцифры?

Comment: Если корневой УЦ Минцифры может выполнить атаку "человек посередине", то наверно её может провести любой корневой УЦ? — в теории да. Но другие УЦ рискуют бизнесом и репутацией, а минцифры ничем (ибо ни того ни другого у них нет)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Минцифры рискует получить срок, так как обслуживает не только частных пользователей, но и госструктуры.

Comment: Я готов поставить свой автомобиль на то, что уж кто-то, а минцтфры выкрутится в случае, если будет виновато в утечке данных. Стаж...

Comment: Срок? Министерство (Да даже и министр)? В России? За исполнение указания какого-нибудь ФСБ? С чего бы?

Comment: Я вообще про MitM, а не утечку писал. А MitM будет по прямому указанию спецслужб, так что о каком сроке речь? Да и с утечками есть сомнения. Базы данных всевозможных ведомств можно чуть ли не в открытую (а в 90х можно было и в открытую) купить и что-то не припомню я никаких реальных судов и сроков…

Comment: Я, конечно, не разбирался в функционировании SSL/TLS, но мне кажется, что корневой сертификат минцифры должен функционировать, только если сайт работает с шифрованием по ГОСТ, а таких единицы. И тогда атака "человек посередине" на каком-нибудь почтовом сайте или социальной сети невозможна: трафик не идёт через "человека посередине".

Comment: @maestro теоретически ничего не мешает зашифровать трафик между клиентом и mitm ГОСТом, а между mitm и сервером обычными RSA/AES, так что это должно работать для любых сайтов (правда, для этого нужен будет браузер с поддержкой ГОСТ-шифрования, но вот нижеупомянутый Тындекс.Браузер такую поддержку как раз имеет)

Comment: @andreymal ГОСТ-шифрование не требуется. [Сертификат Минцифры](https://www.gosuslugi.ru/tls) вполне себе богопротивный SHA256RSA

Comment: @PakUula я смотрел корневые сертификаты на одном из компьютеров, на котором заставляли устанавливать сертификаты — там был только ГОСТ. Заставляет ли кто-то где-то устанавливать «богопротивную» версию сертификата?

Comment: (впрочем, допускаю, что автор статьи на Хабре устанавливал именно её, тогда да, ГОСТ действительно не нужен)

Comment: @andreymal я так понимаю, министерство зашевелилось, почуяв санкции со стороны зарубежных ИТ компаний, и решило провести "импортозамещение", заменив сертификаты сайтам на "отечественные". Поскольку православных браузеров в стране с гулькин нос, то пришлось импортозамещать и сертификаты с буржуинскими неправославными алгоритмами.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Атака, упомянутая в комментариях к статье, - это не человек-посередине, а маскарад.

Открывая stackoveflow, откуда вы знаете, что попали именно на stackoverflow? Вам об этом сообщает браузер, показывая в строке адреса замочек. Если супостат сумеет перехватить ваш трафик и перенаправить на свой клон сайта stackoverflow, то браузер будет ругаться, ибо ни один доверенный удостоверяющий центр супостату не выдаст сертификат на имя `*.stackoverflow.com`.

Все нормальные удостоверяющие центры проходят регулярный аудит безопасности и, в частности, клянутся без проверок сертификаты не выдавать. Без такой клятвы их не включат ни в [базу Mozilla](https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/mozilla/CACertificatesInFirefoxReport), ни в дефолтное хранилище [доверенных корневых сертификатов MS Windows](https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/microsoft/IncludedCACertificateReportForMSFT). Поэтому получение маскарадного сертификата в нормальных удостоверяющих центрах требует разработки и проведения какой-нибудь шпионской операции. Без этого никак.

Теперь о ненормальных удостоверяющих центрах. Читай, минсвязи/минцифры. Они ни в чём не клялись, аудит безопасности не проходили, поэтому легко могут по просьбе некоей третьей стороны взять и выпустить сертификат для `*.stackoverflow.com`. Если супостаты контролируют сетевой периметр, то вооружившись этим сертификатом они могут перенаправлять трафик вместо IP адресов stackoverflow на свои заглушки. И браузер счастливого пользователя минсвязовского корневого сертификата не заметит подмены: доменное имя совпало? - совпало; корневой сертификат доверенный? - доверенный. Значит и вправду открыт сайт stackoverflow. Маскарад удался!

Вместо stackoverflow вы можете подставить любое другое доменное имя.

Разумеется, для реализации такой атаки необходимо, чтобы
а) третья сторона имела возможность перехватывать трафик
б) минсвязи не мог отказать третьей стороне в выпуске левых сертификатов

Но смычка "погоны в штатском" + "госструктура" этим требованиям вполне удовлетворяет. Поэтому компьютеры с установленным корневым сертификатом недоверенных удостоверяющих центров, расположенные внутри периметра, контролируемого "погонами в штатском", рискуют стать жертвами маскарада.

Как-то так.

PS. Аналогичная фигня может приключиться со счастливыми пользователями Тындекс.Браузера. Вы знаете, каким именно сертификатам он доверяет? Что именно скрыто в недрах бинарника? Вот то-то же.

Comment: ответ вполне логичный, только, к сожалениею, построен на трёх ошибочных допущениях: 1. "люди в погонах" существуют исключительно внутри границ рф. 2. смычка "людей в погонах" и "капиталистов" невозможна. 3. скандалов с «нормальными» удостоверяющими центрами никогда не было.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin боюсь, не понял ваш комментарий. 1. Как связаны зарубежные "люди в погонах" на атаку "маскарад" внутри границ РФ? Речь шла именно о рисках внутри РФ. 2. Что-то я сомневаюсь в том, что какие-нибудь DigiCert или GlobalSign будут генерировать левые сертификаты по запросу ФСБ. Наверное, ФСБ это в принципе смогут, только им гораздо проще зайти в Минцифру. 3. Конечно были, но вопрос был о рисках распространения именно Минцифрового сертификата. Я вижу его в том, что российские государственные УЦ изначально скомпрометированы рисками вмешательства силовых ведомств.

Comment: @PakUula, не соглашусь с вами, что установка корневого сертификата открывает атаку только типа маскарад. Думаю, тут может иметь место и "Man in The Middle", в котором злоумышленник не подменяет трафик, а лишь пассивно прослушивает его (меняется лишь сертификат).